# Duplicate symbol declaration for class name and imported class

Tags: php, oop

This is my class:

```
namespace Controller\Reference;

use \Classes\Admin;

class Admin extends Controller
{
    public $data;
}
```

If I want `use \Classes\Admin;` I get this error:

> Duplicate symbol declaration

But if I use `AS` like `use \Classes\Admin AS Admin1;` I not get any error

I don't want use `AS` and change my class name to `Admin1`

How I can use `Admin` class name and use `use \Classes\Admin;` without aliasing the class name?

Comment: You can't, it would be 2 different classes with the same name. If you don't want to use `AS` (not sure why) don't put `use` at the top and simply use the complete Classname with Namespace to access the second Admin class. E.g. `new \Classes\Admin()`

Comment: Why is giving it an alias (using `AS`) an issue? Is this purely for the aesthetics, or is there a "real" reason? After all, this is literally the purpose for the `AS` keyword here. You can call it what ever you want, something that makes more sense than specifically `Admin1`. I'm always wary when the only description of the issue is _"I don't want..."_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have 2 symbols with the same name. It would make code ambiguous and impossible to parse.

Either you alias one of the classes (with the `as` keyword), or you use fully qualified name for the external class.

```
class Admin extends Controller
{
    public $data;

    public function foo() {
        $admin = new \Classes\Admin();
    }
}
```

In any case, there is really no practical reason for not using the alias, but if your code standards, style guide or whatever precludes you from aliasing a class... simply don't do it and do without the import.